# How to tell if the function is called from an output buffering callback?

Tags: php, output-buffering

In a function, how can I find out if it's been called from an output buffering callback (not necessarily directly)?

```
function foo() {
    if (magic here ????)
        $log->write("foo:Callback") 
    else
        $log->write("foo:Normal")
}

function calls_foo() {
    ...stuff
    foo();
}

calls_foo() // should log foo:Normal

ob_start('calls_foo')

    ...stuff

// should log foo:Callback at the end of the script
```

Comment: do you need a generic solution? otherwise you could just add a parameter to foo($calledBy=xxx) and set this in your calls_foo()

Comment: Whatever you're doing, it looks like a dangerous mess of unmaintainability to me. Good luck debugging something like that.

Comment: @Nebel54: I have no control over the code that calls the function, I can change only the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `$debug = debug_backtrace()`. If the debug array is 1 long then you get called from main which means this is an ob callback called at the end of the request. Then you can iterate the array and look at the `'function'` key of each array for an ob flushing function.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but this seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 2):

The function [ob_get_status()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-status.php) returns an array containing information on the current status of output buffering.